# Structural Path of element in C

Tags: c, structure

Hi Friends I am new at structures. I am trying to get path of elements present inside the structures.
For ex:

If I have:-

---

```
struct abc
{
    struct def
    {
        struct lmn
        {
            int a1;
            int a2;
            int a3;
        }lmn;

        struct pqr
        {
            int b1;
            int b2;
            int b3;
        }pqr;

    }def;

}abc;

int *p_alphabet = &abc;
```

---

the path for indivdual elements would be like

```
abc.def.lmn.a1;

abc.def.pqr.b1;
```

If I have a pointer p_alphabet, is there any way I can get the exact path of each and every element and I can store them in an  array, so that I dont need to write each and every one of them(just in case if we are having 1000 of such integers defined inside those structures).

Comment: Yes, you can place an array inside a structure, access is like `abc.def.lmn.a[987]`

Comment: Are you looking for something like `int *a1 = &p_alphabet->def.lmn.a1;`?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to store in an array, the path or the element? Do you want to preprocess the access of the structure, or access it as an array on run-time? Can you be more clear please?

Comment: i think you need this `struct abc{ struct def { struct {int a,b,c;}ghi[1000];}; };`. then you can do `abc.def.ghi[index].a_OR_b_OR_c;`

Comment: @fanl I want to store the path of the elements and use them using the array indexes at run time.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter I am looking for a general approach to access each element just by a pointer.

Comment: @ring0 you are right! We can place an array inside structure. But what if we are provided a situation where instead of an array, multiple elements of different datatypes are present? So I am looking for a general apporoach by storing the exact addresses of elements to access them at run time using an array in which I can store path of each and every element.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way in C to iterate over different members of a struct. So something like this:

```
struct X {
    int a1;
    int a2;
    int a3;
} x;

int *x_members[3];
for (m in x)
    x_members[m_index] = &m;
```

does not exist. What you can do is to make the struct hold arrays by itself. Then index the array by constants representing the name of the variables. Limitation of this is that all the types should be the same (or let's say compatible). For example:

```
enum X_members {
    X_A1,
    X_A2,
    X_A3
};

struct X {
    int members[3];
} x;
```

Then you can have:

```
int *x_members[3];
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    x_members[i] = &x.members[i];
```

or directly use the struct like this:

```
int xa1 = x.members[X_A1];
```

Nested structs could imply nested arrays, or one array indexed with proper enum names such as `X_STR1_STR2_A5`.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is a Lookup array.

```
struct abc
{
    struct def
    {
        struct lmn
        {
            int a1;
            int a2;
            int a3;
        }lmn;
        struct pqr
        {
            int b1;
            int b2;
            int b3;
        }pqr;
    }def;
}abc;

int* lookupArray[] = { &abc.lmn.a1, ... };
```

Comment: Did you see the part where he said: _so that I dont need to write each and every one of them_?

Comment: Lol, so tell me, how your approach can avoid the programmer from "writing each and every one of them?"

Comment: Well, at least _once_ you should do it, i.e. when you define the structure. You repeat them though, once when you define the struct, once when you create the lookup array. In my answer, you only write the variables once (which is inevitable anyway).